# Fundamental group of unit circle union $x$ axis and positive $y$ axis.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I want to confirm whether the space retracts to wedge of sum of circles and therefore fundamental group is $Z*Z*Z$. Because it's circle with one diameter and one half diameter( which retarcts onto a point) so resulting space is circle with one diameter that retracts onto $S^1\vee S^1$. I am not sure whether this is correct or not? If anyone can confirm it would be really helpful.

Comment: More like wedge sum of three circles. BTW what does it have to do with covering spaces?

Comment: Ok probably you are right as this half line would give another wedge after contracting the subcomplex i.e that line ? Right?